# Java BufferedWriter object with utf-8

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I have the following code and I want to make the outputstream use utf-8.  Basically I have characters like `é` that appear as `&#233;` so it looks like an encoding issue.

I've seen lots of examples that use...

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(path),"UTF-8");
```

My current code though is...

```
BufferedWriter out = new 
BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(DatabaseProps.fileLocation + "Output.xml"));
```

Is it possible to define this object as UTF-8 without having to use the OutputStreamWriter?

Thanks,

Comment: Why can't you use an OutputStreamWriter?

Comment: Or better, why can't you use an XML serializer? And if you are using an XML serializer, why aren't you letting it handle the encoding?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

No. `FileWriter` doesn't let you specify the encoding, which is extremely annoying. It always uses the system default encoding. Just suck it up and use `OutputStreamWriter` wrapping a `FileOutputStream`. You can still wrap the OutputStreamWriter in a BufferedWriter of course:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter
    (new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Or, [as of Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-):

```
BufferedWriter out = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(path));
```

(Of course, you could change your system default encoding to UTF-8, but that seems a bit of an extreme measure.)

Comment: Hmm, I did that but I still get &#233; for é.  Does that mean the issue is earlier in the stack?  In the db it's stored as é but when I connect with jdbc:sqlserver://...... it writes the found field as &#233; in my file.  The string is not intentionally being changed in anyway.

Comment: @david99world: It's not clear what you mean, but nothing in the code you've shown is going to be creating XML/HTML entities for you. It does indeed sound like the problem is somewhere else. I'm sure you'll already have the `&#233;` in your string before you write it to the buffered writer.

Comment: The problem might that the program you are using to read your file is not configured for utf-8.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much, I wasn't aware this had to be configured at read as well as write, thank you :)

Comment: For future readers, Apache Commons IO [FileWriterWithEncoding](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/output/FileWriterWithEncoding.html) is also an option

Comment: @Chris: Well these days I'd just use Files.newBufferedWriter - no need for a third party lib.

Answer (score 5):

You can use improved FileWriter, improved by me.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Eugene Chipachenko
 * Date: 20.09.13
 * Time: 10:21
 */
public class BufferedFileWriter extends OutputStreamWriter
{
  public BufferedFileWriter( String fileName ) throws IOException
  {
    super( new FileOutputStream( fileName ), Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ) );
  }

  public BufferedFileWriter( String fileName, boolean append ) throws IOException
  {
    super( new FileOutputStream( fileName, append ), Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ) );
  }

  public BufferedFileWriter( String fileName, String charsetName, boolean append ) throws IOException
  {
    super( new FileOutputStream( fileName, append ), Charset.forName( charsetName ) );
  }

  public BufferedFileWriter( File file ) throws IOException
  {
    super( new FileOutputStream( file ), Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ) );
  }

  public BufferedFileWriter( File file, boolean append ) throws IOException
  {
    super( new FileOutputStream( file, append ), Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ) );
  }

  public BufferedFileWriter( File file, String charsetName, boolean append ) throws IOException
  {
    super( new FileOutputStream( file, append ), Charset.forName( charsetName ) );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) for FileWriter explains,

> The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are acceptable. To specify these values yourself, construct an OutputStreamWriter on a FileOutputStream.

There's no reason you can't construct your BufferedWriter on top of the OutputStreamWriter though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the method, *Files.newBufferedWriter(Path path, Charset cs, OpenOption... options)*

As requested by Toby, here is the sample code.

```
String errorFileName = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader(HeaderKey.ERROR_FILE_NAME.getKey());
        String errorPathAndFile = dir + "/" + errorFileName;
        writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(errorPathAndFile),  StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);
        try {
            writer.write(MESSAGE_HEADER + "\n");
        } finally {
            writer.close();
        }
```

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.