# Java FileWriter lost special characters

Tags: java, special-characters, filewriter

I've this code

```
 //write a file in a specific directory
public static void writeFile(String comment, String outputFileName) {
    FileWriter fWriter = null;
    BufferedWriter writer = null; 
    try {
        fWriter = new FileWriter(outputFileName,true);
        writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
        writer.write(comment);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

But when I save the file in outputFileName, it lost every special character.

File output format is .txt

Some solution?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Already answered... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998905/java-bufferedwriter-object-with-utf-8

Comment: There is no such thing as a "file output format". `txt` is just an extension. You could call a text file "foo.exe" for all the OS cares. What matters here is that you use a `Writer` which converts the characters you give it into bytes, and the bytes which are output depend on the encoding use. And since you don't specify any, well, the default platform encoding is used...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FileWriter` uses the platform-default encoding. It's very rarely a good idea to use that class, IMO.

I would suggest you use an `OutputStreamWriter` specifying the encoding you want - where UTF-8 is almost always a good choice, when you *have* a choice.

If you're using Java 7 or higher, [`Files.newBufferedWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) is your friend - and with Java 8, there's an overload without a `Charset` parameter, in which case UTF-8 is used automatically.

Comment: Another solution to ensure that the characters are indeed writable is to use an `OutputStreamWriter`, since a version of it accepts a `CharsetEncoder` as an argument which you can use to `.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)` (conversely, there is a version of `InputStreamReader` accepting a `CharsetDecoder` as an argument)